NASM - Converting User Input To Integers
I want the user input to be compared with the "num" variable. it of course doesn't work as intended. when I debug it with gdb and observe the value it is something random like 0xa3404856 and I don't understand why.
this is the code:
section .data
enter_msg                   DB      "Enter Your Guess : ", 0
enter_msg_len               equ     $-enter_msg
invalid_input_msg           DB      "Invalid Input !!!", 0x0a, 0
invalid_input_msg_len       equ     $-invalid_input_msg
input_out_of_range          DB      "Input Out Of Range !!!", 0x0a, 0
input_out_of_range_len      equ     $-input_out_of_range
too_high_msg                DB      "Your Guess Is Too High !!!", 0x0a, 0
too_high_msg_len            equ     $-too_high_msg
too_low_msg                 DB      "Your Guess Is Too Low !!!", 0x0a, 0
too_low_msg_len             equ     $-too_low_msg
win_msg_1                   DB      "You Won ! The Number Was ", 0
win_msg_1_len               equ     $-win_msg_1
win_msg_2                   DB      " And You Guessed It In ", 0
win_msg_2_len               equ     $-win_msg_2
win_msg_3                   DB      " Guesses !", 0x0a, 0
win_msg_3_len               equ     $-win_msg_3

num                         equ         64

section .bss
    guess resb 32
    guesses resb 8

section .text
global _start

_start:
    %macro print 2
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, %1
        mov edx, %2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro

    %macro input 2
        mov eax, 3
        mov ebx, 2
        mov ecx, %1
        mov edx, %2
        int 0x80
    %endmacro

    %macro exit 0
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80
    %endmacro

    %macro compare 2
        mov eax, %1
        mov ebx, %2
        cmp eax, ebx
        jg higher
        jl lower
        je win
    %endmacro

    print enter_msg, enter_msg_len
    input guess, 32 
    mov ebx, num
    mov eax, [guess]
    cmp eax, ebx
    jl lower
    jg higher
    jz win

lower:
    print too_low_msg, too_low_msg_len
    jmp _start

higher:
    print too_high_msg, too_high_msg_len
    jmp _start

win:
    print win_msg_1, win_msg_1_len
    print num, 2
    print win_msg_2, win_msg_2_len
    print guesses, 4
    print win_msg_3, win_msg_3_len
    jmp end

end:
    exit

The thing that makes me more confused is why the code above doesn't work but this code works :
print enter_msg, enter_msg_len
input num1, 8
print enter_msg, enter_msg_len
input num2, 8

mov eax, [num1]
mov ebx, [num2]
cmp eax, ebx
jg higher
jl lower
je win


Where do you convert the input to integer?

I don't... I want to know how

0x0a is the newline, the other bytes are ASCII digits like '3'.  See NASM Assembly convert input to integer?
